# SQL: conditional string split then group by Min value then join again

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, split, readonly

I'm new to the programing languages and SQL, and trying my best to explain my issue in a good way.

I'm working in large planning department where I arrange the maintenance of rented equipments for more than one client, my only source to get all different equipment's and different clients with maintenance schedules and details is a **"READ ONLY" access to the DB** from our main branch .

The return is like this

```
    Col1          |          Col2          | Col3      |     Col4
------------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------------------
  equipment type  | Identification/Plate # | Client ID |Mech_3_mailage/1.6_60%/
                  |                        |           |Elec_2_mailage/1.6_20%/
                  |                        |           |Elec_2_Year_-10%/    
                  |                        |           |Tyrs_1_OFF_Road/1.6_-45%       
------------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------------------
```

My issue is with COL4 where i get all the schedules and calculations in one cell for each equipment.

The only thing can help is the pattern

```
(maintenance shop)_(Procedure)_(Calculation)_(percentage%)
```

what make it harder is that there is more than one calculation for each procedure and shop so sometime I get same equipment and same shop and same procedure but different calculations, beside sometime in the calculation I get '/' , so I have to use '%' as the delimiter and after I have to remove '/' if present of the return value, and the

I tried this code:

```
SELECT 
    Col1, Col2, Col3, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN LEFT (value, 1) = '/' 
           THEN RIGHT (value, (LEN(value) - 1)) 
     END)
FROM 
    dbo.clients  
CROSS APPLY 
    STRING_SPLIT (Col4, '%')
WHERE 
    value IS NOT NULL
```

I did some searches and try myself but my knowledge's did not help me to get the table as below :

```
    Col1          |          Col2          | Col3      | Mech_3| Elec_2 |Tyrs_1 |
------------------+------------------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+
  equipment type  | Identification/Plate # | Client ID | 60%   |  -10%  | -45%  |
```

I tried to declare table variable since my access is ready only, but once I add the string split to add its return to the variable table I get error

> 'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name

I am using SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU14; v13.0.5830.85 - X64).

I really appreciate any help or guidance to get this done.

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server** - then most likely you're just running an older version that doesn't support `STRING_SPLIT` just yet. This function was introduced in SQL Server **2016** - to find your version, run `SELECT @@VERSION` and look at the result

Comment: hello @marc_s ,and thanks for replaying , for you question , yes it is `sql-server` and im using` Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU14) (KB4564903) - 13.0.5830.85 (X64) ` ,,

Comment: In addition to needing SQL Server 2016, [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) also requires a database compatibility level of 130. It could be that your database was migrated from an older version of SQL Server but hasn't been upgraded to the SQL Server 2016 compatibility level yet via [alter database ... set compatibility_level ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level)